# how to add additional in php query or jquery

Tags: php

i have query php like this

```
<?php
include('../config.php');

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    if(isset($_POST['pasar'])){
        $code = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pasar']);
        $queryPeriode = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tb_periode WHERE code_pasaran = '".$code."' ORDER BY no DESC LIMIT 10");

        $data = [];
        while ($result = $queryPeriode->fetch_assoc()) {
            $data[] = [
                "periode" => $result['no'],
            ];
        }
        echo json_encode($data) ;

    }
}
?>
```

my js code is like this

```
$("#pasaran").on('change',function(e) {
        $("#periode").html("");
        let code = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "?page=get_data_priode",
            data: {pasar:code},
            dataType: "json",
        })
        .done(function( data ) {            

            $.each( data, function( key, value ) { 
                $( "#periode" ).append("<option value="+value.periode+">"+value.periode+"</option>");
            });

        });

        e.preventDefault(); 
    });
```

the result is like this
[image]

but i want is the result after 1521 have result 1522
how can i do it?
can someone teach me? how to do like that?
me already tried to searching my quested in google
but still no have answer

Comment: Add data in your database or change the LIMIT in your query.

Comment: the last result form database is 1521